# Is there any way to change label names in Qlik Sense?

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

So I have a table with two columns: location name and coordinates.

I created a map visualization using the coordinates and, of course, the labels on the side menu are the coordinates (as you can see in the pic below).

Is there any way to change those labels, so that the corresponding location names appear instead of the coordinates?

[image]

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get what you want add the Location Name to the map as a dimension (instead of the coordinates) and then under Location on that map layer select the Coordinates field (it will by default use the Location Name so change this).

If you want to simplify this you can use tags in your script to say that the Coordinates field is the location data for the Location Name. You can read more about that [here](https://www.ometis.co.uk/enable-qlik-sense-self-service-with-geo-tagging/), but for example:

```
TAG FIELD [LocationName] WITH '$geoname', '$relates_Coordinates';
TAG FIELD [Coordinates] WITH '$geopoint', '$relates_LocationName';
```

This should then mean that when you add LocationName to a map it will automatically know to use the Coordinates to plot the location rather than LocationName.

Comment: No problem. Feel free to up vote the answer and accept it then :)